# C# String array inside int arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, string, int

I need an `array` of `integer arrays` and `string` in C#

```
[
    ["Item 1",[1,2,3,4,5,6]],
    ["Item 1",[1,2,3,4,5,6]],
    ["Item 1",[1,2,3,4,5,6]],
    ["Item 1",[1,2,3,4,5,6]]
]
```

I can not think of any correct possible approach to this problem. I came to this snippet below.

```
string[,] items = new string[10, 2];
for(int 1 = 0; i<10; i++){
    items[i, 0] = "Item " + i;
    items[i, 1] = new int[10];
}
```

How can I get the array I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, int[]> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int[]>();

// Add Item:
myDictionary.Add("Item 1", new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6});
```

Be aware that the key (string) must be unique if you use a dictionary.

or use tuples:

```
Tuple<string, int[]>[] myTuples = new Tuple<string, int[]>[5];
myTuples[0] = new Tuple<string, int[]>("Item 1", new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 });
// Access string with: myTuples[0].Item1
// Access int[]  with: myTuples[0].Item2
```

Or since C#7.0 you can use named tuples:

```
(string MyString, int[] MyIntArray)[] myTuples = new (string MyString, int[] MyIntArray)[5];
myTuples[0] = ("Item1", new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6});

// Access string with: myTuples[0].MyString
// Access int[]  with: myTuples[0].MyIntArray
```

Comment: Could also define your own class with string and int[] properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of tuples:

```
(string,int[])[] items = new (string,int[])[10];
for(int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
 {
 items[i] = ("Item" + i,new int[10]);
 }
```

You can access the values by .Item1 and .Item2:

```
  Console.WriteLine(items[4].Item1); // will output "Item 4"
  Console.WriteLine(items[4].Item2[4]); // will output the 4th value of the 4th array
```

To increase readability even more, you could create your own class and make an array of this class:

```
class Item
 {
 public string Name {get;set;}
 public int[] Values {get;set;}
 }
```

Comment: You could also name the parts of the tuple `var items = new (string Name, int[] Values)[10];`

Answer (score 0):

You can create an class like this

```cs
public class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int[] Array { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
List<Test> testList = new List<Test>();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    Test test = new Test
    {
        Name = "Item 1",
        Array = new int[6]
    };
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        test.Array[j] = j + 1;
    }
    testList.Add(test);
}
foreach (var item in testList)
{
    Console.Write(item.Name);
    foreach (var arr in item.Array)
    {
        Console.Write("\t" + arr);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

**Result**

```
Item 1  1       2       3       4       5       6
Item 1  1       2       3       4       5       6
Item 1  1       2       3       4       5       6
Item 1  1       2       3       4       5       6
```

Comment: Why not using a struct instead of the class?